# How to change the structure of a name field in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, names, flip

I have the following problem.

My table, say tab1, has **name** column as follows "LastName, FirstName". I want to make it so that the column becomes "FirstName LastName".

Any ideas on how this is to be done? Note that there is no comma present, but i guess that can be easily removed once I figure out how to actually flip the first and the last names.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to restructure your table, or do you want to change the way it is output? Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: You definitely must change a table structure, not field. It must be 2 separate fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace @NAME with your real value:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(@NAME, LOCATE(",", @NAME) + 1)) AS prename, TRIM(SUBSTR(@NAME, 1, LOCATE(",", @NAME) - 1)) AS surename
```

This will extract the prename and surename part, now you can insert/modify the data as you want to.

Answer (score 2):

- It would be better to split the name column into two fields, *FirstName* and *LastName*, so that you can format them in any way you want, and still sort on last name.
- Use `substring` and `substring_index` to find comma's and split on them. See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but I would not do this under any circumstances. You will lose any chance to reliably tell apart last name and first name. Consider the following names:

```
Bridget St John
Boutros Boutros Ghali
Karl-Theodor Maria Nikolaus Freiherr von und zu Guttenberg
```

I recommend keeping separate "last name" and "first name" columns. You can concatenate them as you please when you do your output.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET name2=CONCAT (TRIM(SUBSTR(name, LOCATE(",", name) + 1)), ' ', TRIM(SUBSTR(name, 1, LOCATE(",", name) - 1)))
```